# Shell script to search for a string from a file and show number of instances per hour

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script to search for the string "/ABCDEFG/" and get its count hourly for a particular date from the printed timestamp in the logs.

Below is a sample log from where I need to take the counts from:

```
2014-06-21 00:00:22,516:        |[http://123.123.123.123:15123/ABCDEFG/    [200]    [REQUEST_STATUS,0;] [NO-ERROR] [134mSec]
2014-06-21 00:00:22,531:        |[http://123.123.123.123:15123/ABCDEFG/    [200]    [REQUEST_STATUS,0;] [NO-ERROR] [160mSec]
2014-06-21 23:59:54,920:        |[http://123.123.123.123:15123/ABCDEFG/    [200]    [REQUEST_STATUS,0;] [NO-ERROR] [149mSec]
2014-06-21 23:59:54,923:        |[http://123.123.123.123:15123/ABCDEFG/    [200]    [REQUEST_STATUS,0;] [NO-ERROR] [164mSec]
```

Below is the manual command that can be used to get the count:

```
grep "/ABCDEFG/" abc.log |grep "2014-06-21 00" | grep "[200]"|wc -l
grep "/ABCDEFG/" abc.log |grep "2014-06-21 01" | grep "[200]"|wc -l
grep "/ABCDEFG/" abc.log |grep "2014-06-21 03" | grep "[200]"|wc -l etc
```

Comment: Did you want to get only the `/ABCDEFG/` count for each particular date?

Comment: yes, for each hour for each day

Comment: Are the lines actually double-spaced as you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk '$1 ~ /2014-06-21/ && $3 ~ /ABCDEFG/ && $4 == "[200]" {
         ++cnts[int(substr($2, 1, 2))]
     }
     END {
         for(i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
             printf("%02d: %4d\n", i, i in cnts ? cnts[i] : 0);
     }
' logfile
```

You could make it a shell script. The following takes from 1 to 3 parameters. If the second isn't supplied, it defaults to "ABCDEFG"; if the third isn't supplied, it defaults to "logfile". (Obviously you can change those defaults.)

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -vDATE="$1" -vSTR="${2:-ABCDEFG}" '
     $1 ~ DATE && $3 ~ STR && $4 == "[200]" {
         ++cnts[int(substr($2, 1,  2))]
     }
     END {
         for(i=0; i < 24; ++i)
             printf("%02d: %6d\n", i, i in cnts ? cnts[i] : 0);
     }
' ${3:-logfile}
```

Suppose it's called `myscript`. You can call it in the following ways:

```
myscript 2014-06-21
myscript 2014-06-21 HIJKLMN
myscript 2014-06-21 ABCDEFG anotherlogfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date). Something like this would work:

```
grep '/ABCDEFG/' abc.log | grep "`date +%F`" | wc -l
```